# Google script to edit entire column of spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to google scripts so I am going through the documentation in hopes of finding out how to write the script I need. So far everything I read says that it can't access data outside of it's own cell.

The information is in a google spreadsheet, if excel has a easier solution I can move to that.

The idea is that this script would go through a column some 1000 strings and go to the end of the line and walk backward deleting each character until it passes the first "-", once that occurs it would move to the next row.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: @pnuts Yes everything past the last hyphen in each cell and including the last hyphen in each cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for the example you provided in a comment, otherwise not tested:

In new Google Sheets
Edit
Find and Replace...
Find `(.+)(-[^-].+)`
Replace with `$1`
Search *select your range*
Search using regular expressions *tick*
Replace all.

Comment: This works great! This would eb the answer for google sheets. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned moving to Excel.  If you did that, you could use the following macro:

```
x = 1 'change to starting row of strings
theCol = 10 'change to column the strings are in
Do Until Cells(x, theCol) = ""
    theStr = Cells(x, theCol)
    Cells(x, theCol) = Left(theStr, InStrRev(theStr, "-") - 1)
    x = x + 1
Loop
```

As long as there will always be "-" in the string.  If there is any chance there won't be, make sure you add

```
if InStrRev(theStr, "-") > 0 then
```

before

```
Cells(x, theCol) = Left(theStr, InStrRev(theStr, "-") - 1)
```

Comment: I was ran your macro and it does almost what I want. My fault for not being more clear. I they are URLs website.com/directory/a-page-name-4894789755 I want it to just take off the last hyphen and everything after it.

Comment: Your's works great, marked it up as it did answer the excel part! thanks guys this will save me tons of time.